# calculate pacing for the below requirement

Tags: controller, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

I have to calculate pacing for the below requirement:
#concurrent users: 5000
5 scripts - concurrent users split is 10%, 25%, 20%, 25% and 20%
Volume per hour: 15000, 25000, 2000, 40000, 30000
#transactions per iteration: 5
Timetaken for 1 iteration : 60, 80, 70, 30, 50 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logs from production.  it is very easy to calculate time between top level requests for any two pages by looking at a difference in timestamps.  If you want to go the uber sophisticated route you can have R derive a function that you seed with a random/iteration number for the delays.

Next up, let's take the timetaken for one iteration value of 60 seconds.  Does this include think time between requests, or only the system response time?

We can also go the basic math route.

Script 1:

- 500 users (10%)
- 15000 Iterations per hour
- 30 Iterations per user per hour (calculated 15000/500)
- 120 seconds on average from start of   one iteration to the next (calculated 3600/30)  90-150 Random pacing   (Calculated, average +/- 25%.  rand() is roughly uniform so the   average over time/enough samples will approach the average)
- If the total of all system requests and think times is 60 seconds then you have a pretty goo margin as the system degrades with an additional 30-90 seconds of delay on pacing

Answers in this forum will not replace a mentor.  Your management owes you one for a period of time if you are being asked to deliver in this field.